# Is there a way to return active Uber license plate?

Tags: uber-api

In researching the Uber APIs, I only found the REQUEST-DETAILS call that has license plate as part of the results.  However, it has to be an active request.  Is there a way to enter a license plate and return whether it is an Uber vehicle?  If not, does anyone know of other options to check that a plate number is Uber?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I hope not! Seems rather intrusive.

Comment: This seems to be invalid...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there isn't a way to check if a license plate number belongs to an Uber driver via the Uber API.

Answer (score 0):

In New York, this dataset will list public hire vehicles that are part of Uber.

https://data.cityofnewyork.us/Transportation/For-Hire-Vehicles-FHV-Active/8wbx-tsch